# GCP private DNS does not work

Tags: load-balancing, internal-dns, gcp

I am trying to connect my private load balancer IP with a Private DNS record on port 80. But this configuration does not work unless I add my private IP and DNS record to the /etc/hosts file in the machine that I try to access.

I am using an internal load balancer and Open connect VPN to connect my private network. When i access the load balancer with port 80 and its IP it works but unless i add the dns record in my VM it does not pick the private domain which i configured in GCP private DNS.